# Ошибка в терминале Ubuntu (Buildozer+Kivy)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, kivy

Поставил на Windows VirtualBox Ubuntu с Buildozer.Все сделал по этому гайду: https://habr.com/post/301776/ Вот скрин папки со всем:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что внутри spec файла buildozer:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = ColorS

# (str) Package name
package.name = ColorSApp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
version.filename = %(source.dir)s/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/main.p

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version = 1.2.0

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/pre.jpg

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/ico.jpg

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 14

# (int) Minimum API required (8 = Android 2.2 devices)
#android.minapi = 8

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 21

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use —private data storage (True) or —dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug =
"iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s

[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# —---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# List as sections
#
# You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
# Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
# Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
# Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
# This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#

# —---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Profiles
#
# You can extend section / key with a profile
# For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
# HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
# and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
# Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer —profile demo android debug
```

Версию в main.py прописал:

```
__version__ = "1.0"
```

Захожу в папку со всем этим,ввожу:

```
buildozer android debug
```

Вот,что выдает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('buildozer==0.27', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 980, in run_command
self.target.run_commands(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 85, in run_commands
func(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 95, in cmd_debug
self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 161, in prepare_for_build
self.target.install_platform()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 424, in install_platform
self._install_android_packages()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 383, in _install_android_packages
ver = self._find_latest_package(packages, 'build-tools-')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 349, in _find_latest_package
version = self._process_version_string(version_string)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 318, in _process_version_string
version = [int(i) for i in version_string.split(".")]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0-preview'
```

Пробовал менять версию и в main.py,и в spec файле - не помогает.

Кто знает или хотя бы может разобраться с этой проблемой,-помогите для всеобщего блага,у кого-нибудь позже встанет такой же вопрос,а ответ уже будет.

Теперь выдает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 978, in <module>
main()
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 975, in main
ToolchainCL()
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 512, in __init__
getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 149, in wrapper_func
build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
File "/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 193, in build_dist_from_args
build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 551, in build_recipes
File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 307, in download_if_necessary
File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 353, in download
File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 151, in download_file
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 240, in retrieve
fp = self.open(url, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 208, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 437, in open_https
h.endheaders(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 864, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 826, in send
self.connect()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1220, in connect
self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 487, in wrap_socket
ciphers=ciphers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 243, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create —dist_name=ColorSApp —bootstrap=sdl2 —requirements=kivy —arch armeabi-v7a —copy-libs —color=always —storage-dir=/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Попробую воспроизвести  ошибку

Comment: >>> version_string = "1.0"

Comment: >>> version = [int(i) for i in version_string.split(".")]

Comment: >>> version   (всё OK )   [1, 0]

Comment: Теперь : >>> version_string = '0-preview'

Comment: >>> version = [int(i) for i in version_string.split(".")]

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0-preview'

Comment: А вот что написано  в  buildozer/docs/source/specifications.rst
"If you don't want to capture the version, comment out both version.regex and version.filename, then put the version you want directly in the version token:

# version.regex =
# version.filename =
version = 1.0  " 
То есть номер версии можно указать в spec файле. Строки version.regex =..  и version.filename =... закомментировать, а строку с номером версии version = 1.0 раскомментировать

Comment: Ещё недочёт нашел. В spec файле version.filename = %(source.dir)s/home/kivy/Desktop/ColorS/main. **p** , а реальное расширение файла main **py**, не **p**  .  Поэтому возможно version.filename просто не был найден.

Comment: @JaponDemon Спасибо большое, через час попробобую-отпишусь.

Comment: @JaponDemon Теперь выдает...Добавил

Comment: Ну что делать, читайте лог, раз никто не отвечает в этой теме  **Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2**

Comment: Вот тут `version = [int(i) for i in version_string.split(".")]
` , скорее всего у тебя в version_string версия написана через запятую (либо в этой строке есть другие символы, отличные от цифр и точки)